# Word request: miscellaneous/supplementary (historical) accounts

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a site focusing on performing artists and I need a category for all the articles that (1) don't belong anywhere else (2) more often than not, offer behind-the-scenes insights and miscellaneous historical accounts.

My research so far:

- *behind the scenes*: too narrow, excludes misc. articles
- *miscellany, miscellaneous*: too generic/boring
- *trivia*: too flippant
- *ancillary*: too technical
- *addendum*: too formal
- *annals*: too formal

Comment: Asking for a word to represent supplementary historical accounts is fine as is asking for a word for articles that don't belong anywhere else. Asking for one that represents both of these disparate categories is too localised to be of use to anybody else. This question will very likely be closed in its current form.

Comment: If you can't create an interesting neologism for your **grab-bag** articles, I'd suggest that you use what everyone will understand: *Supplementary Material/Articles". It's just one word, so does anyone really care if it's boring? As a reader, I'd want to understand the meaning, not be entertained by a one-shot label.

Comment: [**The Green Room**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_room) is where actors waiting to go on gossip, reminisce and backbite.

Answer (score 1):

How about one of these?

- *Hodgepodge*
- *Mishmash*
- *Potpourri*
- *Odds & Ends*

They may not carry the connotation of "historical accounts," but those terms seem:

- less formal than *annals* or *addendum*
- less technical than *ancillary*
- less flippant than *trivia*
- less generic than *miscellaneous*

so maybe one of them might work, or at least nudge you in a good direction.

P.S. I like *mishmash*; it seems to carry a *performing artist* connotation for some reason. ([Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mishmash) lists one meaning of *mishmash* as *medley*.)